# Can't correctly shift my values on uint64?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I can't understand how I can shift bits correctly in my C++ code:

```
uint64 iSteamId = FCString::Atoi(*gz_pid);

uint8 UniverseAccount = (iSteamId << 56) & 0xFF; // X
uint8 LowestBit = (iSteamId >> 63) & 0xFF; // Y
uint32 AccountNumber = (iSteamId << 32) & 0x7FFFFFF; // Z

gz_SteamId += "STEAM_" + \
    FString::FromInt(UniverseAccount) + ":" + \
    FString::FromInt(LowestBit) + ":" + \
    FString::FromInt(AccountNumber);
```

The image shows how you can read some recommendations from Steam how it must be done:

[image: steam wiki recommendations]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding how bits and shift work in C++.

To begin: The lowest (least significant) bit is number `0`. On a 64-bit number the highest (most significant) bit is number `63`.

Shifting to the *right* moves high bits to the lower positions, filling up with zero bits at the top. Shifting to the *left* move bits to the higher positions, filling up with zero bits at the bottom.

If you have the byte `0b1000000` (decimal `128`) and shift it one position to the *right* (with `>>`) you get `0b01000000` (decimal `64`).

If you have the byte `0b00000001` (decimal `1`) and shift it one position to the *left* (with `<<`) you get `0b00000010` (decimal `2`).

---

For your problem:

The lowest bit doesn't need any shift to be had, it's always the lowest bit which you get with e.g. `iSteamId & 1`.

The next 31 bits you shift down one bit to remove the lowest bit, and mask with the the 31 lowest bits: `(iSteamId >> 1) & 0x7fffffff`.

For the top eight bits you shift down 56 bits and just let the compiler truncate the result: `iSteamId >> 56`.

These shifts assumes Intel [little-endian system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: I found this method on php code, and tried to use it, but In this case it not works correctly too.. nothing to understand :l

Comment: @AlexDeroza That is one of the dangers of [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). If you take a few steps back, and try to learn from the ground up, you will be able to figure out how to do this yourself without the need to attempting to copy-paste some code you don't understand.

Comment: I understood my mistake.

`uint64 iSteamId = FCString::Atoi(*gz_pid);`

This converts only to int32, instead `Strtoui64` must be used. But I can't understand how I can use it in my case. Can u help me, how I can correctly to do this. thx a lot. This's its template: `uint64 TCString<T>::Strtoui64( const CharType* Start, CharType** End, int32 Base )`